# Elastic Search Document Update taking too long when retrieved by alias

Tags: json, elasticsearch

Here is the situation.

1) There is an existing document (let's say the index is `baseball-a`

2) `baseball-a`, `baseball-b`, and `baseball-c` are aliased to `baseball`

3) Update a document in baseball-a

```
POST /baseball-a/1/_update?pretty'
{
    "doc": { "my_name": "Casey at the bat2"}
}'
```

4) now if I do a `GET baseball-a/1/` everything is updated

5) but if I do a search

```
 POST /baseball/_search?pretty
    {
      "query": { "match": { "id":  "1" } }
    }
```

then the document that is returned has the old my_name of "Casey at the bat" (missing the '2') but 15 minutes later it shows up... how do I fix this or speed it up?

Comment: you could try [refresh](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html)  before search and see if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Basically you need to look at the refresh_interval for the alias by doing

`GET /baseball/_settings`

Mine was set to -1 and it should be set to either 1s or 5s
Additionally after I manually ran this command

`POST /baseball/_refresh`

it also worked but that is just a hassle... let elastic do it for you automatically. Now if I could only figure out why I can't set the refresh inteval correctly [Updating ElasticSearch interval_refresh when aliased](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591654/updating-elasticsearch-interval-refresh-when-aliased)