# Updating ElasticSearch interval_refresh when aliased

Tags: json, elasticsearch

Right now I have 3 indices

1. baseball-a
2. baseball-b
3. baseball-c

They are aliased in elastic to baseball and have a refresh interval of "-1" I can check this by checking 
`GET /baseball/_settings`

Now if I updated that refresh interval with

`PUT /baseball-a/baseball/_settings 
{ 
    "index" : { "refresh_interval" : "1s"} 
}`

and then I do

`GET /baseball/_settings`

the changes are not reflected but if I do

`GET /baseball-a/baseball/_settings`

then the changes are there

How come the alias is not picking up the changes? (what am I doing wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you're using in your PUT request is not correct, you need to separate the index (i.e. `baseball-a`) and the alias (i.e. `baseball`) with a comma, not with a forward slash.

```
PUT /baseball-a,baseball/_settings 
{ 
    "index" : { "refresh_interval" : "1s"} 
}
```

Also, since you're using the alias, you don't need to specify the index name

```
PUT /baseball/_settings 
{ 
    "index" : { "refresh_interval" : "1s"} 
}
```

Comment: I would up-vote your answer if I actually had the ability to :)... .still getting there